# ggvis density plot + xlim + xlab

Tags: r, ggvis

I'm trying to learn how to use ggvis. Basically, I want to reproduce this ggplot2 graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
m <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt))
m + geom_density(aes(fill="orange"), size=2, alpha=.9) + xlim(0,5) + theme_bw() + 
  xlab("x label") + guides(fill=FALSE)
```

Right now I have this:

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, fill := "red") %>% 
  layer_densities() %>%  
  add_axis("x", title = "Weight") %>% 
  scale_numeric("x", domain = c(0, 5), nice = FALSE)
```

But I don't know how to do xlim(0,5)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you want `clamp = TRUE` in your call to `scale_numeric`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The credits for the answer should go to hadley, thanks!

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, fill := "red") %>% 
  layer_densities() %>%  
  add_axis("x", title = "Weight") %>% 
  scale_numeric("x", domain = c(0, 5), nice = FALSE, clamp = TRUE)
```